# How do I bump my own question?

Tags: support, questions, bump, front-page

I would like to be able to bump old questions to the front page (so they appear together with the newly posted questions). Is there any way to do that currently?

Comment: Just do meaningful edits to improve it, so it will appear in the  _active_ questions tab.

Comment: Pretty sure `?sort=newest` questions can *only* be newly posted (or newly migrated) questions. If you want to draw more attention to your question, you can also consider adding a bounty.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ *bump so my question gets on top* .... very meaningful ...

Comment: Just to be clear about this, up front: Do *not* edit posts **just to bump them**, moderators can and do lock posts to prevent further edits if a question owner abuses editing in this fashion. If a question is important enough to you, place a bounty on it. Editing should only be used to make *meaningful changes* such as better examples or new insights that may help make the question easier to answer.

Comment: See the [FAQ on when questions are bumped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped) on the Uber Meta.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: The [home page](https://stackoverflow.com/) (for logged in users) shows a mix of new and recently active posts.

Comment: The question you should ask is not *How do I get more eyes on my questions?* but rather *Why did the many people seeing my question did not answer it?*

Answer (score 4):

**[Bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/484288)** (an ideal way IMO)

Offer a bounty to attract more people to answer your question which has been on-site for at least 48 hours by clicking on start a bounty option.

**Edit the Question** (should be meaningful, do not abuse edit option)

Whenever a post is modified or has a new answer we can see that activity in **[Active Tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Active)** 
You can see in an image that the *question Why does downvoting...* is modified by user *fzyzcjy*

[image]

Comment: The front page of the site (*home*) shows more than just new questions. Edited questions can appear on that page too, and older posts that [meet certain criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184485/community-seems-to-be-bumping-new-questions-more-frequently-than-usual/184511#184511) are automatically bumped to be visible there.